# Регулярное выражение для url'ов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка для урлов:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}(\.)[a-zа-яё]{1,4}(\:[0-9]+)?(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)?)+(\?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#]+(=[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#]+)?((\&[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#]+(=[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#]+)?)+)?)?
```

но почему-то не работает для русских доменов (пример.рф например). Причем, пример.ru работает, то есть регулярка не работает для русских доменов верхнего уровня. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

[Ссылка с регуляркой и примерами](http://regexr.com/3g75t)

Comment: Выражение очень неэффективно. Но, конечно, если добавить везде, где `a-z` `а-яё`, [можно заставить его работать и с русскими буквами](http://regexr.com/3g760).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, пока затык на домене первого уровня.

Comment: @АртемТеллур домены больше второго уровня у вас не предусмотрены?

Comment: @Darth, предусмотрены конечно. Просто вопрос пока возник только с доменами верхнего уровня.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо большое, действительно работает! Не могли бы вы еще пояснить, в чем неэффективность выражения?

Comment: @АртемТеллур: Во-первых, нечитабельно. Во-вторых, захватывающие группы использованы вместо незахватывающих. В-третьих, `(\/?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+~#]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)?)+` вызывает опасения, так как находится в середине выражения, по краям опциональные шаблоны с обязательным в середине + квантификатор на целой группе. Ну, есть и мелочи вроде экранирования того, что не нужно, лишние захватывающие группы... Короче, регулярка в режиме "только для чтения".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо большое! Буду совершенствоваться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведённой выше регулярке можно добавить диапазон русских букв везде, где предположительно будут буквы, т.е. рядом с латинницей `a-z` добавить `а-яё`.

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zа-яё0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zа-яё]{1,4}(?::[0-9]+)?(\/?[-a-zа-яё0-9@:%_\+~#]+(\.[a-zа-яё0-9]+)?)+(\?[-а-яёa-z0-9@:%._\+~#]+(=[-a-zа-яё0-9@:%._\+~#]+)?((\&[-a-zа-яё0-9@:%._\+~#]+(=[-a-zа-яё0-9@:%._\+~#]+)?)+)?)?/gi
```

[См. демо](http://regexr.com/3g760)

Можно добавить модификатор `/i`, тогда не нужно указывать буквы в обоих регистрах.

Comment: Не берусь поправлять выражение дальше. Если возникнут сложности, напишите комментарий.